# ListView data deleted and data updated, notifyDataSetChanged called, but no updated of my list

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView with custom adapter which is populated from local sqlite database. When user long click the item and choose 'delete', dialog will popup to confirm the action again and item will be deleted after confirmed click. 
My problem is that the item was deleted from database and the arraylist( dataset for adapter ) was updated, but the ListView isn't updated eventhough I've already called the notifyDataSetChanged().
//The delete method is set on AlertDialog/PositiveButton click listener < ListView ContextMenu listener.

I've checked or tried the following things, but still...

1. Rebuild it (go onCreate), listview will show correctly then, so should be not other issue.

2. I called the same adapter, have confirmed by same hashCode 

3. mListView.setAdapter((ListViewAdapter)(ListViewer.mListView.getAdapter())); 

4. allResArray.clear(); loadData();

Can anyone help me please? Thanks. I've been stuck on it for 2 days!!

Here is my code:

```
private static ListView mListView;                  
private ListViewAdapter mListViewAdapter;
public String[] strListRID;
public List<List<String>> allResArray;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
    setView(R.layout.listviewer);
    init(); 
}

public void init(){
    setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
    setTitleBar(R.drawable.title_home, 0, R.drawable.title_add, 0, 
            0, 0, R.drawable.titlebar_title, 0);
    initListView();     
}

//MainListView initialization    
private void initListView(){
    boolean SD_STATE = checkSDState();
    allResArray = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    loadData();

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    mListViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, SD_STATE, allResArray);
    mListView.setAdapter(mListViewAdapter);
    Log.i("mListViewAdapter", String.valueOf(mListViewAdapter.hashCode()));

    mListView.setCacheColorHint(0x00000000);    

    // Click listener to ListView
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            goIntent(5, strListRID[position]);
        }   
    });   

    // ContextMenu listener to ListView
    mListView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {       
        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            menu.setHeaderTitle(R.string.conext_menu_title);       
            menu.add(0, 0, 0, R.string.conext_menu_edit);
            menu.add(0, 1, 0, R.string.conext_menu_delete);
        }       
    });  
}

@Override  
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 0:         //Edit
        goIntent(5, strListRID[menuInfo.position]);
        return true;    
    case 1:         //Delete
        showDeleteDialog(strListRID[menuInfo.position], menuInfo.position);
        break;                  
    default:
        break;        
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item); 
}

private void loadData() {
    allResArray = getAllDatabaseRes();
    int size = allResArray.get(0).size();
    strListRID = allResArray.get(0).toArray(new String[size]);
}

/**
 * AlertDialog: confirm before delete data
 * Remove it from ArrayList and notifyDataSetChanged() to adapter
 * @param strListRID
 */
private void showDeleteDialog(final String strListRID, final int position) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.dialog_notice);
    dialog.setMessage(R.string.text_delete);        
    dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_delete, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (delRes(Integer.parseInt(strListRID))){
                                    int size =((ListViewAdapter)(mListView.getAdapter())).mResArray.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                    ((ListViewAdapter)(mListView.getAdapter())).mResArray.get(i).remove(position);
                }
                ((ListViewAdapter)(ListViewer.mListView.getAdapter())).notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.i("mListViewAdapter_check", String.valueOf(((ListViewAdapter)(ListViewer.mListView.getAdapter())).hashCode()));
                showShortToast((String) getResources().getText(R.string.text_record_delete_ok));
            }
            else{
                showShortToast((String) getResources().getText(R.string.text_record_delete_ng));
            }   
        }
    });
    dialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.text_no, null);   
    dialog.show();      
}
```

delRes() code in BaseActivity:

```
 /**
 * Delete the specific rid record from database
 * @return boolean DEL_OK
 * @throws SQLException
 */
protected boolean delRes(int strRID) throws SQLException {    
    boolean DEL_OK = false;
    String deleteWhere = "rid=?";
    String[] deleteWhereValue = { String.valueOf(strRID)};
    Log.i("rid to delete", deleteWhereValue[0]);

    int delrow = dbHelper.delete(tables[0], deleteWhere, deleteWhereValue);
    Log.i("delrow", String.valueOf(delrow));

    if (delrow == 1){
        DEL_OK = true;
    }
    return DEL_OK;
}
```

And the logCat:

```
02-09 15:19:59.744: I/mListViewAdapter(28235): 1163110296
02-09 15:19:59.784: I/tmp(28235): /sdcard/Photo/20120208164204.jpg
02-09 15:19:59.814: I/tmp(28235): /sdcard/Photo/20120208163627.jpg
02-09 15:19:59.854: I/tmp(28235): /sdcard/Photo/20120209151917.jpg
02-09 15:20:05.514: I/menuInfo.position(28235): 1
02-09 15:20:08.634: I/rid to delete(28235): 10
02-09 15:20:08.674: I/delrow(28235): 1
02-09 15:20:08.674: I/mListViewAdapter_check(28235): 1163110296
```

Current solution: Set a new listviewadapter

```
    /**
 * AlertDialog: confirm before delete data
 * Remove it from ArrayList and notifyDataSetChanged() to adapter
 * @param strListRID
 */
private void showDeleteDialog(final String mRID, final int position) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.dialog_notice);
    dialog.setMessage(R.string.text_delete);        
    dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_delete, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            if (delRes(Integer.parseInt(mRID))){    
                int size = allResArray.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                    allResArray.get(i).remove(position);
                }
                strListRID = allResArray.get(0).toArray(new String[size-1]);

                //((ListViewAdapter)(mListView.getAdapter())).notifyDataSetChanged();
                mListView.setAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), true, allResArray));
                showShortToast((String) getResources().getText(R.string.text_record_delete_ok));
            }
            else{
                showShortToast((String) getResources().getText(R.string.text_record_delete_ng));
            }   
        }
    });
    dialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.text_no, null);   
    dialog.show();      
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you doing at this statement ? for (int i = 0; i < allResArray.size(); i++){allResArray.get(i).remove(position);}

Comment: List<List<String>> allResArray; which includeds 8 List<String>. this is to remove the selected item out of every list.

Comment: Sorry 4 asking too many question, but tell me few things..1)What your listview actually shows to the user? List objects ? 2) Your Arraylist is bind to your adapter(I agree), but instead of removing items from this arraylist, you are removing single items from the list inside that ArrayList. How do you think that will affect the appearance of your listview to end user ?

Comment: Thanks for your questions, but I'm a bit confused. The listview pass allResArray as param to listviewadapter to build up a view including several textview and imageview. It's my customized listviewadapter. Isn't it the purpose to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()? It can call getView() to refresh listview just like setAdapter() did, do I have any misunderstanding? thanks. btw, I've tried setAdapter() too, no luck...

Comment: Did you find any solution to this ? I think your getView() is unable to update your list.

Comment: The current solution is to create a new adapter. I don't think it's the right thing to re-init one, UI is always reloading and shown on the top position, quite bad user experience I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the row specified directly from your adapter, and then calling notifyDataSetChanged(). Or you can just create new adapter, iterate your ArrayList and adding data to your new adapter, then set this adapter to your ListView.

Comment: indeed, to create a new adapter can work well, but I just don't get it why notifyDataSetChanged() cannot work and update the listview? Trace the arraylist, it becomes different arraylist (hashCode=1) after delete called (removeAll or clear method), but I'm sure arraylist only initialized once. so, is it the problem?

Comment: I just realized the deleting you said should be operated on the (ListViewAdapter)(mListView.getAdapter())).mResArray, right? I tried it, the dataset was correct, but listview still not updated! (Code included listviewadapter updated in the question)

Comment: It is not the problem with initializing arraylist once, when you delete data from your arraylist, you should do this again: `mListViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, SD_STATE, allResArray);
    mListView.setAdapter(mListViewAdapter);`

Comment: thanks and yes, init one listviewadapter can update the listview, but how exactly I did wrong with notifyDataSetChanged()? btw, the current solution will roll up the listview on the top position, user need to scroll down then...

Comment: I am not sure about what went wrong because I had also problems with that method. And about scrolling the list, you should keep some index of selected item in arrayList and then just call `listview.setSelection(index) `

Comment: If any of this solved your problem and helped, whoever answered, you should accept that answer officially

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this same problem.  After deleting the item in the backing store and notifying the Adapter by calling notifyDataSetChanged(), it seems that ListView.confirmCheckedPositionsById() is called internally as the Adapter goes about it's work in response to the notifyDataSetChanged() . **ONE solution** as you noted was to replace the Adapter with a new one -- but as you noted, this messes up where the user is in the list, and the user MUST scroll down again -- that's bad.

So what I did was to check in my derived Adapter for running out of range in the array holding the data, and when out of range, just return an item id of 0.  (Note that I have stable ID's in this Adapter and perhaps that helps) In this case, my backing store is mTC and I do this in the call to the Adapter that checks on the Item ID:

> class TaskAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
>
> ...
>         @Override
>         public long getItemId(int position) {
>             // update this after pulling tode from Task.java in the future
>             if (position>=mTC.size()) 
>                 return 0;
>             return mTC.getTask(position).hashCode();
>         }
>   ...
>   }

This solves the problem and the internal code of the BaseAdapter seems to realize that the last item is no longer valid... and everything works.  I hope this helps for those that have run into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you all the data from ArrayList. In that case on deletion an entry from the DB what you can do is as follows,

1. Clear allResArray
2. Load data again from database in the same array
3. notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: Hi, I did tried it by allResArray.clear(); loadData(); but it still not works. I've checked the data correctness too, no matter in remove() or reload way, the list was not updated.